# How to reset a random number engine?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I am trying to use the C++11 approach to random number generation:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    std::normal_distribution<double> normal(0, 1);
    std::mt19937 engine; // Mersenne twister MT19937
    auto generator = std::bind(normal, engine);

    int size = 2;

    engine.seed(0);
    normal.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << generator() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    engine.seed(1);
    normal.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << generator() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    engine.seed(0);
    normal.reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << generator() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0.13453
-0.146382

0.46065
-1.87138

0.163712
-0.214253
```

That means that the first and the third sequence are not identical even if they are seeded with the same number. Please, what am I doing wrong? Is the

```
std::normal_distribution<double>
```

Just a function in the mathematical sense (produces y out of x deterministically) or am I missing something? If it is just a function, what does the reset method actually do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are binding the engine and the distribution, such the following calls on reset won't affect the bound function.

The solution is to bind references to the engine and the distro

```
auto generator = std::bind(std::ref(normal), std::ref(engine));
```

Comment: That was it. I guess I have to learn the STL much more :) It works perfectly with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: `auto generator = std::bind(normal, std::ref(engine));` is enough I guess.

Answer (score 12):

The problem you are having is with `std::bind`. `std::bind` makes copies of its arguments. The reason `std::bind` makes copies is because the function will be called at some unknown point in the future when the arguments may no longer exist. This means your calls to `engine.seed()`, etc. are useless. Using `std::ref` you can bind your arguments by reference which will give you the expected output.

```
auto generator = std::bind(std::ref(normal), std::ref(engine));
```